# EC2 Instance doesn't become managed after installing SSM Agent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2008-r2, ssm

I've installed **SSM** Agent (**2.2.607.0**) on **Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard** instance with the EC2 Config (**4.9.2688.0**). After installing it, i cannot see the server on the **Managed Instances** screen. I did the same steps on other servers (Windows and Linux) and it worked.

Tried to uninstall the **EC2 Config**, reinstalled it again with no luck. Tried to install a different SSM Agent version (**2.2.546.0**) with no luck also.

Any thoughts?

Comment: My EC2 instance didn't appear in managed instances when it was in a public subnet, I changed it to a private subnet and it appeared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The agent is installed, but the **instance** still needs the proper role to communicate with the systems manager. Particularly [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-configuring-access-role.html) step of [Configuring Access to Systems Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-access.html).

> By default, Systems Manager doesn't have permission to perform actions
>   on your instances. You must grant access by using an IAM instance
>   profile. An instance profile is a container that passes IAM role
>   information to an Amazon EC2 instance at launch.

You should review the whole configuration guide and make sure you have configured all required roles appropriately.

Comment: Then you'll need to reboot the instance so SSM agent could initialise it with Inventory

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, and of the [four troubleshooting steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-remote-commands.html) - *SSM Agent*, *IAM instance role*, *Service Endpoint connectivity*, *Target operating system type*, it turned out that the problem was **endpoint connectivity**.

My VPC, Subnet, route table, and internet gateway all looked correct (and were identical to another instance which was being managed by SSM). But the instance didn't have a public IP, and without that you can't use the IGW.  You can't use a [VPC endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/setup-create-vpc.html) and an Internet Gateway.  So adding a public IP allowed the instance to connect to SSM and become managed.

Extra complication : I was trying to use EC2 Image Builder, which creates an instance without a public IP.  So there is no way to use Image Builder in a VPC which has an Internet Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

New SSM agent version comes with a diagnostic package.. You can run that to see which prerequisites is missing.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ssm-cli.html